# jquery plugin jformslider hide a slide

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using jquery plugin jformslider
https://github.com/harishuw/jFormslider

my website is a survey website
my html is

```
 <form>
        <ul>
          <li>
                  //first slide will ask r u using android phone(radio button)
                // if no it will show another button r u planning to buy android in future

                //based on this 2 questions i want to show/hide second li slide

         </li>
          <li  call-before="some_function()" > second slide only for android </li>
          <li> third </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
```

i tried `call-before="some_function()"` 
this function is not valuating

but its not working
Please help me

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. `first`, `second` and `3rd` are invalid HTML attributes. You should use a class, or an ID (but has to be unique) instead.

Comment: use attribute call-after="func()" in first slide visit jformslider.com for proper documentation

Answer (score 2):

Give a id to second li

```
<form>
    <ul>
      <li first></li>
      <li id="second"></li>
      <li 3rd></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

then based on first li condition

```
if(li first condition)
{
$('#second').hide()
}else
{
$('#second').show()
}
```

Comment: first check proper documentation for plugins before answering these kind of foolish answers. For this plugin use jformslider.com

Answer (score 0):

use

its very simple you can use

```
$('li:eq(2)').hide();
```

Comment: sorry this is not right answer

Comment: first check proper documentation for plugins before answering these kind of foolish answers. for this plugin use jformslider.com